# Why is it not possible to set a column's alias dynamically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and I want to pass a column alias as a parameter, something like:

```
SELECT u.userLoginName AS @columnName
FROM -- some JOINs
WHERE -- some conditions
```

where `@columnName` can be one of two options and it is set before the SELECT statement according to some condition.
I already know that it can be done only by dynamic SQL, but I don't understand **why?**

I know that the Order of execution of a Query is: FROM and JOINs -> WHERE -> GROUP BY and only then SELECT.

So if at this point I already got the result set, i.e, the finale table, why can't I just rename the column name as `@columnName`? What happens in the background that I miss?

Comment: Because SQL isn't a scripting language. It's not a language like Powershell, which supports the injection of parameters to represent objects, names, etc. A SQL statement must be well defined, and you **cannot** replace parts of a query that require literals with a parameter/variable. The fact that you want to change the column's name (dynamically) implies you have an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info) here.

Comment: This isn't just something that happens in Microsoft's SQL Server, or more specifically in the T-SQL dialect, @DaleK . Other SQL languages often don't support the replacement of literals with variables (I can't think of any that do, but I wouldn't be surprised there's one out there). If they did, it would not be following "standard behaviour".

Comment: Note you *can* set a column's name dynamically, with dynamic SQL. But, if you just want to dynamically change the alias of a column, then that is certainly not a task for the Data Engine and should be in your Presentation Layer.

Comment: Is it true to PostgreSQL as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may answer your question.

A SQL result set is conceptually just like a table:  it has well defined rows and columns and no ordering unless created with an explicit `order by`.

A SQL query is processed in two phases:  it is compiled and optimized, then it is run.  (Happily some databases are now starting to provide dynamic optimization as well, but the queries still go through the compilation phase.)

*All* information about the result set needs to be known during the compilation phase -- and that includes the resulting column names and column types.  Dynamic names would prevent this from happening.  They would only be known during the execution phase.

Note that this applies to *parameters* as identifier as well.  Parameters are substituted at the beginning of the execution phase.

This is not a limitation of any particular database.  It applies to all of them.  I suspect that some more modern databases are implemented in a way that would allow for more dynamic naming, but I don't know of any databases that actually implement it except through dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but you have to use a dynamic query.
Let assume we have the following table

```
Create table #TBL ([Months] VARCHAR(3), Value INT)
INSERT INTO #TBL values
('Jan',20),('Feb',12),('Jan',15),('Mar',25),
('Feb',18),('Jan',9),('Mar',10),('Jan',19)
GO
```

And I want to dynamically set the columns name using variable. I can use the bellow code

```
DECLARE @M VARCHAR(10)='Months',
        @T VARCHAR(10)='Total'
-- Dynamic query to get the column name
DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @qry = 'SELECT  [Months] AS '+@M+',
             sum(Value) as '+@T+'    
      FROM #TBL
      group by [Months]
      DROP TABLE #TBL'
EXEC (@qry)
```

Note the query itself have to be dynamic